# Using EC2 only when under load or incase of failure

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

Is it possible to have most of our server hardware outside of EC2, but with some kind of load balancer to divert traffic to EC2 when there's load that our servers can't handle, or as a backup incase these servers go down?

For example, have a physical server serving out our service (let's ignore database consistency for the moment), but there's a huge spike due to some coolness - can we spin up some EC2 instances and divert traffic off to it?  This is much like Amazon's own auto scaling.

And also, if our server hardware dies for some reason (gremlins eat the power cables for example) - can we route all our traffic over to EC2 instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you will have to code. AWS has [Command Line Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) for doing EC2/Autoscaling/S3 stuff with simple commands in bash or other interfaces and SDKs, like Boto for Python etc.
You can find it here: http://aws.amazon.com/code/

Answer (score 0):

Each Ec2 instance has a public network interface associated with it. Use a DNS `CNAME` record to "switch" your site traffic to the Ec2 instance.  If you need to load-balance across multiple machines you can use round-robin DNS, or start a [ELB](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and put any number of Ec2 instances behind it.

Ec2 infrastructure is extremely easy to scale. *Deploying* your application on top of an Ec2 is a whole other matter. It could be trivial -- or insanely complicated.